# Meaning for = in antlr4

Tags: antlr4

I have a grammar like

`rule1 : GO (count=DECIMAL)? ;`

`rule2 : name '=' expression`

I dont understand the difference between '=' sign in rule1 and rule2

Answer (score 1):

The assignment is a variable assignment. ANTLR4 will generate a member variable named `count` for you, which gets the `DECIMAL` token when matched (since it is optional, `count` might be empty/null).

You can use `count` for instance in your listener code to directly get that value, however you could also just use `DECIMAL` instead. So it's mostly useful for action code or predicates in your grammar. You can refer to such variables by using e.g. `$count`:

```
rule1: GO (count = DECIMAL)? { $count.toString().toInteger() < 4}?;
```

which matches only if `GO` is followed by a value less than 4.

Side note: `toInteger()` is just pseudo code here. Use your target's string-to-int conversion API.